# /dev/graphics/fb0 Device not found

Tags: android, root, framebuffer

I found a lot about /dev/graphics/fb0. It is fast. But It doesn't seems to be working. If i do manually. Neither programmatically. But I am  sure that this feature works on my mobile as i have an application that works using same method.

I have tried to change permission. i have root access.

```
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
```

Permission is changed.

<strike>But when i try to run command</strike>

```
adb pull /dev/graphics/fb0 /mnt/sdcard/tmp
```

I tried to redirect input  using

```
cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /sdcard/frame.raw
```

I get an error saying

```
error : device not found.
```

But nothing works . same error each time.
I am testing on gt-i9500.

Can someone guide me what i am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: This is only supported on some hardware; on other designs the GPU does not make a linear framebuffer available.  That is why adb no longer takes screenshots itself, but rather delegates it to a device specific executable.  Also "adb pull /dev/graphics/fb0 /mnt/sdcard/tmp" is unworkable, since the second path is on your device but must be on your development machine.

Comment: Ok. So why the other program works ?

And the other command cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /sdcard/frame.raw works fine on my other device

Comment: It either knows how to talk to undocumented aspects of the specific GPU, or uses a library which does.  You can spent a couple of days decompiling it if you like, but it's not clear you will end up getting much utility for your trouble.

Comment: I already decompiled & saw the source. The program was using nothing more than this specific command. If there was a library. it would have mention of method screencap.So i am sure that this is only method.The only menthion of screencap i found was lib\armeabi\libjsrn.so in & i think this is system lib only.