# Using the onFrameAvailable() in Jacobi Google Tango API

Tags: google-project-tango

**Question:**  Does anyone know how to get the Tango's color camera image buffer using the Tango Java (**Jacobi**) API `onFrameAvailable()` callback?

**Background:**

I have an augmented reality application that displays video in the background of the Tango.  I've successfully created the video overlay example using the the Java API (Jacobi) following [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/blob/master/VideoOverlaySample/src/com/projecttango/videooverlaysample/MainActivity.java).  My application works fine, and the video is rendered in the background properly.

As part of the application, I'd like to store a copy of the video backbuffer when the user presses a button.  Therefore, I need access to the camera's RGB data.

According to the [Jacobi release notes](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/release-notes), any class desiring access to the camera RGB data should implement the new `onFrameAvailable()` method in the `OnTangoUpdateListener`. I did this, but I don't see any handle or arguments to actually get the pixels:

**Java API**

```
@Override
public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {
    //Log.w(TAG, "Frame available!");
    if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR) {
        tangoCameraPreview.onFrameAvailable();
    }
}
```

as shown, `onFrameAvailable` only has one argument, and integer designating the id of the camera generating the view.  Contrast this with the C-library call back, which provides access to the image buffer:

**C API**

```
TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable(
    TangoCameraId id, void* context,
    void (*onFrameAvailable)(void* context, TangoCameraId id,
                             const TangoImageBuffer* buffer));
```

I was expecting the Java method to have something similar to the buffer object in the C API call.

**What I've Tried**

I tried extending the `TangoCameraPreview` class and saving the image there, but I only get a black background.

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends TangoCameraPreview {


    private boolean takeSnapShot = false;

    public void takeSnapShot() {
        takeSnapShot = true;
    }

    /**
     * Grabs a copy of the surface (which is rendering the Tango color camera)
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620055/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-androids-surface-view
     */
    public void screenGrab2(){

        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        long fileprefix = System.currentTimeMillis();

        View v= getRootView();
         v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        // this is the important code :)  
        // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null          
        v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        v.layout(0, 0, width, height);

        v.buildDrawingCache(true);

        Bitmap image = v.getDrawingCache();

        //TODO:  make seperate subdirctories for each exploitation sessions
        String targetPath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/RavenEye/Photos/";
        String imageFileName = fileprefix + ".jpg";   

        if(!(new File(targetPath)).exists()) {
            new File(targetPath).mkdirs();
        }

        try {           
            File targetDirectory = new File(targetPath);
            File photo=new File(targetDirectory, imageFileName);
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
            image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);          
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            Log.i(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Grabbed an image in target path:" + targetPath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(CameraPreview.class.getName(),"Exception " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(CameraPreview.class.getName(),"Exception " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }


    /**
     * Grabs a copy of the surface (which is rendering the Tango color camera)
     */
    public void screenGrab(){

        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        long fileprefix = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);

        //TODO:  make seperate subdirctories for each exploitation sessions
        String targetPath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/RavenEye/Photos/";
        String imageFileName = fileprefix + ".jpg";   

        if(!(new File(targetPath)).exists()) {
            new File(targetPath).mkdirs();
        }

        try {           
            File targetDirectory = new File(targetPath);
            File photo=new File(targetDirectory, imageFileName);
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
            image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);          
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            Log.i(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Grabbed an image in target path:" + targetPath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(CameraPreview.class.getName(),"Exception " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(CameraPreview.class.getName(),"Exception " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }

    @Override
    public void onFrameAvailable() {
        super.onFrameAvailable();
        if(takeSnapShot) {
            screenGrab();
            takeSnapShot = false;

        }
    }

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

**Where I'm Heading**

I'm preparing to root the device, and then using the `onFrameAvailable` method to cue an external root process such as one of these:

[post 23610900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610900/dev-graphics-fb0-device-not-found)

[post 10965409](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965409/android-take-screenshot-on-rooted-device)

[post 4998527](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998527/android-how-can-you-get-framebuffer-screenshot-on-rooted-device/6970338#6970338)

I'm hoping I can find a way to avoid the root hack.

***Thank you in advance!***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I figured out a way to make it work.

***Update:***  My working solution is here:

https://github.com/stevehenderson/GoogleTango_AR_VideoCapture

I essentially set up a "man (renderer) in the middle" attack on the rendering pipeline.
This approach intercepts the `SetRenderer` call from the `TangoCameraPreview` base class, and allows one to get access
to the base renderer's `OnDraw()` method and the GL context.  I then add additional methods to this extended renderer that allow reading of the GL buffer.

**General approach**

1)  Extend the `TangoCameraPreview` class (e.g. in my example `ReadableTangoCameraPreview`).  Override the `setRenderer(GLSurfaceView.Renderer renderer)`, keeping a reference to the base renderer, and replacing the renderer with your own "wrapped" `GLSUrface.Renderer` renderer that will add methods to render  the backbuffer to an image on the device.

2)  Create your own `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` Interface (e.g. my `ScreenGrabRenderer` class ) that implements all the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` methods, passing them on to the base renderer captured in Step 1.  Also, add a few new methods to "cue" when you want to grab the image.

3)  Implement the `ScreenGrabRenderer` described in step 2 above.

4)  Use a callback interface (my `TangoCameraScreengrabCallback`) to communicate when an image has been copied

It works pretty well, and allows one to grab the camera bits in an image without rooting the device.

**Note:** I haven't had the need to closely synchronize my captured images with the point cloud. So I haven't checked the latency.  For best results, you may need to invoke the C methods proposed by Mark.

Here's what each of my classes looks like..

```
///Main Activity Class where bulk of Tango code is
.
.
.

// Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
mTangoCameraPreview = new ReadableTangoCameraPreview(getActivity());

RelativeLayout preview = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(mTangoCameraPreview);


.
.
.
//When you want to take a snapshot, call the takeSnapShotMethod()
//(you can make this respond to a button)
mTangoCameraPreview.takeSnapShot();
.
.
.
.
.
//Main Tango Listeners
@Override
public void onFrameAvailable(final int cameraId) {
    // Update the UI with TangoPose information
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR) {
                tangoCameraPreview.onFrameAvailable();
            }       
        }
    });
}
```

---

**ReadableTangoCameraPreview Class**

```
public class ReadableTangoCameraPreview extends TangoCameraPreview implements  TangoCameraScreengrabCallback  {

    Activity mainActivity;
    private static final String TAG = ReadableTangoCameraPreview.class.getSimpleName();

    //An intercept renderer
    ScreenGrabRenderer screenGrabRenderer;

    private boolean takeSnapShot = false;

    @Override
    public void setRenderer(GLSurfaceView.Renderer renderer) {  
        //Create our "man in the middle"
        screenGrabRenderer= new ScreenGrabRenderer(renderer);

        //Set it's call back
        screenGrabRenderer.setTangoCameraScreengrabCallback(this);

        //Tell the TangoCameraPreview class to use this intermediate renderer
        super.setRenderer(screenGrabRenderer);
        Log.i(TAG,"Intercepted the renderer!!!");       
    }


    /**
     * Set a trigger for snapshot.  Call this from main activity
     * in response to a use input
     */
    public void takeSnapShot() {
        takeSnapShot = true;
    }   

    @Override
    public void onFrameAvailable() {
        super.onFrameAvailable();
        if(takeSnapShot) {
            //screenGrabWithRoot();
            screenGrabRenderer.grabNextScreen(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
            takeSnapShot = false;           
        }
    }

    public ReadableTangoCameraPreview(Activity context) {
        super(context); 
        mainActivity = context;     

    }

    public void newPhoto(String aNewPhotoPath) {
        //This gets called when a new photo was  grabbed created in the renderer
        Log.i(TAG,"New image available at" + aNewPhotoPath);    
    }

}
```

---

**ScreenGrabRenderer Interface**

*(Overloads the TangoCameraPreview default Renderer)*

```
/**
 * This is an intermediate class that intercepts all calls to the TangoCameraPreview's
 * default renderer.
 * 
 * It simply passes all render calls through to the default renderer.
 * 
 * When required, it can also use the renderer methods to dump a copy of the frame to a bitmap
 * 
 * @author henderso
 *
 */
public class ScreenGrabRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer  {


    TangoCameraScreengrabCallback mTangoCameraScreengrabCallback;

    GLSurfaceView.Renderer tangoCameraRenderer;
    private static final String TAG = ScreenGrabRenderer.class.getSimpleName();

    private String lastFileName = "unset";

    boolean grabNextScreen = false;

    int grabX = 0;
    int grabY = 0;
    int grabWidth = 640;
    int grabHeight = 320;

    public void setTangoCameraScreengrabCallback(TangoCameraScreengrabCallback aTangoCameraScreengrabCallback) {
        mTangoCameraScreengrabCallback = aTangoCameraScreengrabCallback;
    }

    /**
     * Cue the renderer to grab the next screen.  This is a signal that will
     * be detected inside the onDrawFrame() method
     * 
     * @param b
     */
    public void grabNextScreen(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        grabNextScreen = true;
        grabX=x;
        grabY=y;
        grabWidth=w;
        grabHeight=h;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        tangoCameraRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(gl, config);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        tangoCameraRenderer.onSurfaceChanged(gl, width, height);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        tangoCameraRenderer.onDrawFrame(gl);    
        if(grabNextScreen) {
            screenGrab(gl);
            grabNextScreen=false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     * Creates a bitmap given a certain dimension and an OpenGL context
     *  
     * This code was lifted from here:
     * 
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514149/capture-screen-of-glsurfaceview-to-bitmap 
     */
    private Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl)
            throws OutOfMemoryError {
        int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
        int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
        IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
        intBuffer.position(0);

        try {
            gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
            int offset1, offset2;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                offset1 = i * w;
                offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
                for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                    int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                    int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                    int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                    int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                    bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
                }
            }
        } catch (GLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
            return null;
        }

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }


    /**
     * Writes a copy of the GLSurface backbuffer to storage
     */
    private void screenGrab(GL10 gl) {
        long fileprefix = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String targetPath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/RavenEye/Photos/";
        String imageFileName = fileprefix + ".png";   
        String fullPath = "error";

        Bitmap image = createBitmapFromGLSurface(grabX,grabY,grabWidth,grabHeight,gl);
        if(!(new File(targetPath)).exists()) {
            new File(targetPath).mkdirs();
        }
        try {           
            File targetDirectory = new File(targetPath);
            File photo=new File(targetDirectory, imageFileName);
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
            image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);          
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            fullPath =targetPath + imageFileName;
            Log.i(TAG, "Grabbed an image in target path:" + fullPath);      

            ///Notify the outer class(es)
            if(mTangoCameraScreengrabCallback != null) {
                mTangoCameraScreengrabCallback.newPhoto(fullPath);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Callback not set properly..");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Exception " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Exception " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        lastFileName = fullPath;
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param baseRenderer
     */
    public ScreenGrabRenderer(GLSurfaceView.Renderer baseRenderer) {
        tangoCameraRenderer = baseRenderer;     
    }
}
```

---

**TangoCameraScreengrabCallback Interface** 
*(not required unless you want to pass info back from the screen grab renderer)*

```
    /*
     * The TangoCameraScreengrabCallback is a generic interface that provides callback mechanism 
     * to an implementing activity.
     * 
     */
    interface TangoCameraScreengrabCallback {
        public void newPhoto(String aNewPhotoPath);
    }
```

Comment: Awesome - the Java folks are gonna love this, you gave them what Google didn't!

Comment: Yeah it's pretty slow right now, and sometimes hangs the Tango thread when I copy the bits.  I'm going to play with it some more and see if I can't post some demo code...

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried on the latest release, but it was the absence of this functionality that drove me to the C API where I could get image data - a recent post, I think on the G+ page, seemed to indicate that the Unity API now returns image data as well -  for a company that wants to keep scolding us when we don't use Java, it certainly is an odd lag  :-)